# How to use variable $1 from regex to be used in a method C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code but where I have $1 is wrong, I don't know:

```
// [size=4]Size[/size]
sText = Regex.Replace(sText, @"/\[size=([1-7])\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/size\]/i", "<span style='font-size: "+ GetCssSizeByFontSize($1) +";'></span>");
```

I want to use somehow `$1` from regex to be used in my function called `GetCssSizeByFontSize`

```
private static string GetCssSizeByFontSize(string fontSize)
        {
            switch (fontSize)
            {
                case "1":
                    return "xx-small";
                case "2":
                    return "x-small";
                case "3":
                    return "small";
                default:
                case "4":
                    return "medium";
                case "5":
                    return "large";
                case "6":
                    return "x-large";
                case "7":
                    return "xx-large";
            }
        }
```

I want to replace `[size=4]Some text[/size]` with `<span style='font-size: medium;'>Some text</span>` using my function.

How to achieve this using regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't use `/` characters to delimit regular expression patterns in C#, so your pattern should look like this:

```
(?i)\[size=([1-7])\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/size\]
```

But this can simplified to:

```
(?i)\[size=([1-7])](.+?)\[/size]
```

Second, you can pass a [`MatchEvaluator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate to the replace method. This can be a lambda expression, like this:

```
sText = Regex.Replace(sText, 
    @"(?i)\[size=([1-7])](.+?)\[/size]", 
    m => "<span style='font-size: "+ GetCssSizeByFontSize(m.Groups[1].Value) +";'></span>");
```